# docker pull image error: repository does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am running get-login command, and pull a docker image then I got this error. I checked this is the right aws repo so not sure why it didn't work ?

```
 aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-2
```

docker login -u AWS -p QWEDWDWD....dwdswqsS -e none https://123xxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com

```
docker pull 959xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/project:latest
```

Error response from daemon:

> pull access denied for
>   959xxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/project, repository does not
>   exist or may require 'docker login': denied: Your Authorization Token
>   has expired. Please run 'aws ecr get-login --no-include-email' to
>   fetch a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-2)
```

Comment: Yeah. From the op output im not sure that output was evaluated,  but i think maybe not.